# How to find the tangent cone of $A = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: \; y = \sqrt{|x|}\}$ at the origin?

Tags: convex-analysis, tangent-spaces, convex-cone

My problem is pretty much stated in the title. I don't quite know how to approach this. I have the definition of a tangent cone to a set $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ at a point $x$: A tangent vector $l \in \mathbb{R}^n$ to a set $K$ at a point $x \in K$ if
there exists a sequence of positive numbers $d_i$ that converge to $0$ and a sequence of vectors $v_i$ that converge to $0$ with
$$x+ld_i+d_iv_i \in K \quad \forall i = 1,\; 2, \; \ldots $$
The tangent cone is then the set of all tangent vectors.
I do not know how to apply this to the set $$A = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: \; y = \sqrt{|x|}\}$$ at the origin. Intuitively I would have guessed that $\{(u,v)\in \mathbb{R}^2:v =0\}$ satisfies this but I am a little lost.